# Is there any clean procedure by mantra (Sudhhi Mantra) for Mala of Rudraksha?

Tags: mantras, rudraksha

if the mala not maintain clean then it will lead to curse ?
 some of the shop selling the mala  told me it must maintain in clean and more powerful, and if we not maintain properly then it will result the curse, is there any clean procedure with mantra to avoid curse?.

Comment: Ask your guru. People selling malas are shopkeepers; not experts in things spiritual.

Comment: There are something called Rudraksha Samskara Mantras.. but i don't think they will be useful for ur purpose... Also how will the mala accumulate dust if you regularly wear it? It will also bath daily along with you.. Do not worry about what the shopkeeper said..

Comment: use it every day and your fingers will clean it. No need for any washing....

Comment: BTW i said about Rudraksha malas that are worn on the body.. and @SwamiVishwananda is probably telling about Japamalas.. If it's the latter then no need to wash it.. we keep them in their bags..that's all..

Answer (score 1):

Like all the energy stones like crystals and other precious stones, Rudraksha Mala also should be cleansed/ energised periodically so as to shed any negative emotions being attracted to it. The best days to do so are typically “Masa Shivaratri” of every month. There is a detailed procedure for this and can be performed by priest or by self. This is also Rudrabhishekam.

Process 2 (Detailed Ritual)
For an elaborate Rudraksha pujan or blessing following procedure is to be followed: Blessings may be done by the wearer, his Guru or a priest.

Arrange the following items:
Punchgavya ­ Mix of Cow's dung, urine, milk, ghee and curd. In absence use Punchamrit which is mix of unboiled milk, honey, sugar, ghee and curd.
Ganges water in a achamani pot with Kusha grass for sprinkling or a spoon. In absence of Ganges water, clean pure water may be used.
9 leaves of Peepal tree arranged on a plate. Plate for offerings to be placed during Puja. Dhoop, Incense sticks.
Camphor and lamp
Sandal Paste, Aromatic oil.
Rice grains preferably mixed with asthagandha.
Ghee lamp (one wick)
Offerings ­ Cloth, Flower, Fruit, Betel nut ­ Paan, Coconut.

After bath, with a calm and pure mind and clean body sit on an Asan (mat or clean carpet) facing east.
Wash Rudraksha with Punchagavya or Punchamrit.Then wash with water / Ganges water.

Place Rudraksha in a plate with 9 leaves of Peepal tree. Place an empty plate in front of this plate for offerings Chant “Om Namah Shivaya” 3 times.
Sprinkle water over yourself and all items of Puja and chant
“Om Apavitrah Pavitro Va Sarva Vastan Gatopi Va Yah Smaret Pundari Kaksham Sa Bahya Bhyantarah Shushed”
“Om Gurubhyo Namaha, Om Ganeshaya Namaha, Om Kula Devatabhyo Namaha, Om Ishta Devatabhyo Namaha, Om Mata Pitribhyam Namaha"
Place water on right hand with spoon of Achamani and sip after each of these 3 mantras “Om Keshavaya Namaha, Om Narayana Namaha, Om Madhavaya Namaha"
Put water on right hand and pour on ground: “Om Govindaya Namaha"
Do three short rounds of Pranayama breaths.

“Om Pranavasya Parabrahma Rishihi Paramatma Devata Daivi Gayatri Chandaha Pranayamae Viniyogaha”
Sprinkle water on Rudraksha with Kusha grass or a spoon from Achamani “Om Sadyojaatam Prapadyaami Sadyojataajava Namo Namaha Bhave Bhavenaati Bhave Bhavasvamaam Bhavodbhavay Namaha”
Take a flower and dip in Sandal paste and aromatic oils and touch on the beads “Om Vamdevaya Namah, Jyeshthaay Namah, Shreshthay Namah,
Rudraay Namah, Kaalay Namah, Kala Vikarannaay Namah, Bal Vikaranaay Namah, Balaah Namah, Bala Pramathanaay Namah, Sarva Bhoot DamanaayNamah, Manomanaay Namah.”

Offer Dhoop to the rudraksha beads
“Om Aghorebhyo Ghorebhyo Ghor Ghor Tarebhayaha Sarvebhya Sarva Sharvvebhyo Namaste Astu Rudra Roopebhyana”
Again take a flower and dip in Sandal paste and touch on beads
“Om Tatpurushaaya Vidmahe Mahadevaay Dheemahi Tanno Rudraha Prachodayaat”
Chant Eeeshan mantra
“Om Eeshaanah Sarvavidyaanam Eeshwar Sarvabhootaanaam Brahmaadipati Brahmanaadhipati Brahma Shivome Astu Sadaa Shivom”
Sada Vasantam Hridaya Ravinde Bhavam Bhavani Sahitam Namami”
Chant Gayatri mantra 3 times

“Om Bhur Bhuvah Swaha
Om Tat Savitur Varenyum Bhargo Devasya Dhimahi Dhiyo Yonaha Prachodayat”
Chant Surya mantra 3 times

“Om Bhu Om Bhuvaha Om Swaha Om Maha Om Janaha Om Tapaha Om Satyam” Repeat and touch each after each mantra, right eye, left eye, forehead
“Om Apo Jyothi
Raso Amtritam
Brahma Bhu Bhuvaha Swarom”
Chant Mahamrityunjaya mantra 5 times and offer rice to a plate before rudraksha after each round “Om Haum Joom Sah, Om Bhur Bhuvaha Swaha, Om Triambakam Yajamahey
Sungandhim Pushti Vardanam, Urvar Ukamiva Bandhanan, Mrityor Muksheeya
Mamritat, Om Swaha Bhuvaha Bhu Om Sah Joom Haum Om”
Chant Beeja mantra 9 times each

"Om Namah Shivaya, Om Hreem Namah, Om Namah, Om Kleem Namah
Om Hreem Namah, Om Hreem Hum Namah, Om Hum Namah, Om Krom Kshom Rom Namah"
Bow or supplicate, then chant this last prayer :
"Om Purnamada purnamidam prunad purnamudyachite Purnasya purnamadaya purna mevaya shishyate
Om Shanti Shanti Shanti"

The blessed and energised Rudraksha can now be worn on the body as specified or placed at worshiping place.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the **[Devi Bhagwat Puran](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57383.html)** mentions the below procedure for the stringing as well as ritual cleansing of the Rudraksha rosaries before use:

> Īśvara said :-- O Kārtikeya! Now I will speak how to count the Japam (repetition of the mantra) with the rosary. Hear. The face of Rudrākṣam is Brahmā; the upper summit point is Śiva and the tail end of Rudrākṣam is Viṣṇu. The Rudrākṣam has two-fold powers :-- It can give Bhoga (Enjoyment) as well as Mokṣa (Liberation).

> Then string or tie together, like a cow’s tail, and like the snake’s coiling a body, twenty-five five faced Rudrākṣa seeds, thorny and of red, white, mixed colours bored through and through. The rosary is to taper as a cow’s tail tapers down. In stringing the beads into a rosary, it should be seen that the flat face of one Rudrākṣam is in front of the flat face of another Rudrākṣam; so the tail, the pointed end of one, must come in front of the tail or the narrower end of another. The Meru or the topmost bead of the string must have its face turned upwards and the knot should be given over that. The rosary, thus strung, yields success of the Mantra (mantra-siddhi).

> **When the rosary is strung, it is to be bathed with clear and scented water and afterwards with the Pañchagavya (cow-dung, cow urine, curd, milk, and ghee); then wash it with clear water and sanctify it with the condensed electrical charge of the Mantra. Then recite the Mantra of Śiva (Six limbed), with “Hūm” added and collect the rosaries. Then repeat over them the Mantra “Sadyojāta, etc.”, and sprinkle water over it one hundred and eight times.** Then utter the principal mantra and place them on a holy ground and perform Nyāsa over it, i.e., think that the Great Cause Śiva and the World-Mother Bhagavatī have come on them.

> Thus make the Samskāra of the rosary (i.e., purify it) and you will find then that your desired end will be attained successfully. **Worship the rosary with the Mantra of that Devata for which it is intended.** One is to wear the Rudrākṣa rosary on one’s head, neck or ear and controlling oneself, one should make japam with the rosary.

This is the ritual to be followed before wearing the Rudraksha beads or using them as a Japa-mala.